# How can I open an external python script on PyQt5 With Push button

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm creating a small GUI to help me calculate the RGB of an image by clicking on a button I created the RGB calculator program in a separate code and create on Qt designer the push button and table widget to help me see the result but I don't know how to run the external RGB program in the QT prgram

this is the GUI program

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from qtpy.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess

# creat a class to import the UI file
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("python.ui", self)
        #for framless window
        #flags = QtCore.Qt.WindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        #self.setWindowFlags(flags)
#main

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    welcome = MainWindow()
    welcome.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

and this is the RGB calculator code

```
from PIL import Image 

i = Image.open("test.jpg", "r")
pixels = i.load() 
width, height = i.size
nb_pixels=width*height
all_pixels = []
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        cpixel = pixels[x, y]
        all_pixels.append(cpixel)

#calculate the RGB value of all pixels in the picture 
red=sum(i[0] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
green=sum(i[1] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
blue=sum(i[2] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
#Calculate luminance
luminance=0.2126*red+0.7152*green+0.0722*blue


print ("red=",red)
print ("green=",green)
print ("blue=",blue)
print ("luminance=",luminance)
```

All I want is to push the button an the information shows in the tabel something like this
[image]

and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a python module (basically your UI and backend located together)

Then, in QT program you just import your RGB calculator program (you will need to wrap your code into a function (see below) and import this function, eg `from calculator import calculate`)

after that, you just bind an onclick event in QT. When user presses the button the imported function will be called and executed)

```
from PIL import Image 

def calculate():
    i = Image.open("test.jpg", "r")
    pixels = i.load() 
    width, height = i.size
    nb_pixels=width*height
    all_pixels = []
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            cpixel = pixels[x, y]
            all_pixels.append(cpixel)
    
    #calculate the RGB value of all pixels in the picture 
    red=sum(i[0] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
    green=sum(i[1] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
    blue=sum(i[2] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
    #Calculate luminance
    luminance=0.2126*red+0.7152*green+0.0722*blue
    
    
    print ("red=",red)
    print ("green=",green)
    print ("blue=",blue)
    print ("luminance=",luminance)
```

Do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make database first to show data on table widget.you better use sqlite which is a built-in python database.then you should connect your button to calculate func  and a function to insert your database to table.I recommend use threading for this so you gui window do not freeze.here is the sample:

```
        import sqlite3
        import threading
        
        conn = sqlite3.connect("machine.db", check_same_thread=False)
        mycursor = conn.cursor()
    
        mycursor.execute(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name} ")
        mycursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE {table_name} (red varchar(50),green varchar(50),blue varchar(50),luminance varchar(50))""")
    
    
        class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
            def __init__(self):
                super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
                loadUi("python.ui", self)
                self.{your button name} = QtWidgets.QPushButton(clicked=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.calculate()).start()
                )
                        
    def calculate(self):
        i = Image.open("test.jpg", "r")
        pixels = i.load() 
        width, height = i.size
        nb_pixels=width*height
        all_pixels = []
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                cpixel = pixels[x, y]
                all_pixels.append(cpixel)
        
        #calculate the RGB value of all pixels in the picture 
        red=sum(i[0] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
        green=sum(i[1] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
        blue=sum(i[2] for i in all_pixels)//nb_pixels
        #Calculate luminance
        luminance=0.2126*red+0.7152*green+0.0722*blue

        mycursor.execute(
                    f"insert or ignore into {table_name} values(?,?,?,?)",
                    (
red,green,blue,luminance
                    ),
                )

        conn.commit()
    
        mycursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {table_name}")
        result = mycursor.fetchall()
    
                for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
                    self.tableWidget.insertRow(row_number)
                    for column_number, column_data in enumerate(row_data):
                        item = str(column_data)
                        if column_number == 0:
                            item = self.imagelabel(column_data)
                            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row_number, column_number, item)
                        else:
                            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                                row_number, column_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(item)
                            )
                self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(50)
```

Comment: thank you so much for you help I'll try it and let you know if it worked